# Unable to connect to horizon via JavaScript SDK

Tags: nodes, horizon

I am just getting started with Stellar. I run a node connected with test network with the following command.

```
docker run --rm -it -p "8000:8000" -v "/home/prashant/stellar/steler-node:/opt/stellar" --name stellar stellar/quickstart --testnet
```

I created an account and received some Lumens using friendbot.

Now when I try to connect to horizon using `npm request module`. I am able to query balance. This script works perfectly.

```
const request = require('request-promise');

const options = {
  method: 'GET',
  uri: 'http://localhost:8000/accounts/GD7HLQRVOFPYJBQ4HJY74LJZ5FXM5YPTZA55IKXZNSEPLF7UYEWDBJ4G',
  json: true // keep this true else you need to parse the response
}

request(options)
    .then(function(account){
        //account = JSON.parse(response);
        console.log('Balances for account: ' + account.account_id);
        account.balances.forEach(function(balance) {
          console.log('Type:', balance.asset_type, ', Balance:', balance.balance);
        });
    })
    .catch(function(error){
        console.log("Unable to get balance.");
        console.log(error);
    });
```

But when I try to connect using SDK, check following script.

```
var StellarSdk = require('stellar-sdk');
StellarSdk.Network.useTestNetwork();

const account1 = {
    publicKey:  'GD7HLQRVOFPYJBQ4HJY74LJZ5FXM5YPTZA55IKXZNSEPLF7UYEWDBJ4G'
};

var server = new StellarSdk.Server('http://0.0.0.0:8000');

// the JS SDK uses promises for most actions, such as retrieving an account
server.loadAccount(account1.publicKey).then(function(account) {
  console.log('Balances for account: ' + account1.publicKey);
  account.balances.forEach(function(balance) {
    console.log('Type:', balance.asset_type, ', Balance:', balance.balance);
  });
})
.catch(function(e){
    console.log("error occured in getting balance");
    console.log(e);
})
```

I get error:

> error occured in getting balance { Error: write EPROTO
>   139981321324352:error:140770FC:SSL
>   routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:unknown
>   protocol:../deps/openssl/openssl/ssl/s23_clnt.c:827:
>
> ```
> at _errnoException (util.js:999:13)
> at WriteWrap.afterWrite [as oncomplete] (net.js:883:14) errno: 'EPROTO', code: 'EPROTO', syscall: 'write' }
> ```

However I have tested the later script connecting to setller's test node : 
**https://horizon-testnet.stellar.org** and it worked like charm.

Did I miss anything while setting up the node? Or I am calling the functions in wrong way?

**Edit 1:**
I tried using `https` in my url to horizon. I got hit by error:

> throw new Error("Cannot connect to insecure horizon server");

Answer (score 7):

Okay. So found the solution with help of @Bartek Nowotarski.

My local horizon didn't have SSL certificate. So I had to either

- add SSL to the horizon
- Use it without SSL: `var server = new StellarSdk.Server('http://127.0.0.1:8000', {allowHttp: true});`

Not sure why this was not documented anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

Or you may add this line in your JS:

```
process.env.NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED = "0";
```